# Curvature tensor for a particular Hilbert manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

My question involves an infinite dimensional Hilbert manifold with a Riemannian metric.

> My question is: What is the form of the  curvature tensor for a infinite dimensional Hilbert manifold with a Riemannian metric?

Note- please try not suggesting books or long reads. I'd like an equation for the curvature tensor and I'll probably ask questions abort terms. Please and thank you.

Comment: I act so innocent despite my name 

Comment: PLEASE stop downvotint

Comment: What the frick is the problem with the question. It is as clear as day what I'm asking you people.

Answer (score 1):

I've never more than looked lightly into infinite-dimensional manifolds, but much of the finite theory carries over, provided things converge.

The Lie bracket is definable by $[X, Y](f) = X(Y(f)) - Y(X(f))$ for smooth functions $f$.

The Levi-Civita connection $D_VW$ is definable by the Koszul formula: 
$$\begin{align}2\langle D_VW, X\rangle &= V\langle W, X\rangle + W\langle V, X\rangle -X\langle V, W\rangle\\
&- \langle V, [W, X]\rangle + \langle W, [X, V]\rangle + \langle X, [V, W]\rangle\end{align}$$

The curvature tensor is definable as $$R_{XY}Z = D_{[X,Y]}Z - [D_X, D_Y]Z$$

(I am using the conventions of Barrett O'Neil's Semi-Riemannian Geometry - some Authors have the opposite definition for $R$)

As far as I can see, all of those definitions work in infinite dimensions.

Comment: I probably should have said this in the question, my theory requires me to be able to differentiate this with respect to the metric.

Comment: Could you perhaps say what these terms mean and how to do that math in a "tensor with indices form"

Comment: These are the *basic* elements of the theory of Riemannian manifolds. This is a forum for answering questions, not teaching you the entire theory. In the above, $f$ is a smooth function on the maniford, and $W, X, Y, Z$ are vector fields over the manifold. $R$ is the curvature tensor. As for what it looks like in terms of local coordinates, I assumed you already knew. It looks exactly the same as the finite dimensional version. The only difference is the range over which the indices covers, and the type of summation used.

Comment: I didn't ask for that

Comment: i asked a single question to be answered but ok. I never said the whole theory, now did I?

Comment: The Lie bracket, the Levi-Civita connection, and the curvature tensor are the basic objects on which the theory of Riemannian manifolds are built. If you are unfamiliar with them, then you need more instruction than can reasonably be provided in this forum. You need to study them in textbooks or face-to-face tutoring. And please drop the attitude. It will get you nowhere.

Comment: I am familiar with them and I'm  learning. I'm understanding it more bit by bit. That answer did help, btw.

Comment: And I didn't use to have a problem on here, attitude wise. It's just I can't stand it when my question is as clear as day and stupid people downvote it anyways.

Comment: It is indeed frustrating, but there is nothing you can do about it but to develop a thicker skin. And recognize that even when you disagree with someone, that doesn't make them stupid. Also recognize that being smart does not make you wise. The term "sophomore" is not a joke. It's an astute observation.

Comment: ok, I will work on that.

Comment: So how do you  Calculate the D[x,y] and the [Dx, Dy] terms?

Comment: I take the latter one to be a commutator, but I may be wrong. Thanks for this, btw.

Comment: $D_V$ is the Levi-Civita connection operator with repect to the vector field $V$ so $D_{[X, Y]}$ is the connectior operator with respect to the vector field $[X, Y]$. And you are correct: $[D_X, D_Y]W = D_X(D_YW) - D_Y(D_XW))$. Note also what I said in the previous comment: In terms of indicial notation, everything looks exactly the same as it does for finite dimensions. But, if you have a countable basis for your Hilbert space, then you are summing $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$. If you have continuum basis on a set $A$, then you are integrating over $A$, etc.

Comment: K, I'm starting to get this it's helping. 1. Score for correctly getting the commutators   

Comment: Assumption.  2. Not to sound picky but its for my understanding. Could you perhaps write out this D[x,y] term? 3. Does it have to be Levi-Civita? 4. This ones a bit different; is the covariant derivative the same in a hilbert manifold as it is on an 'ordinary' Riemannian manifold? I'm full of questions. If you can't tell.

Comment: $$\begin{align}2\langle D_{[X,Y]}Z, V\rangle &= [X,Y]\langle Z, V\rangle + Z\langle  [X,Y], V\rangle -V\langle  [X,Y], Z\rangle\\
&- \langle  [X,Y], [Z, V]\rangle + \langle Z, [V,  [X,Y]]\rangle + \langle V, [ [X,Y], Z]\rangle\end{align}$$ (3) If you want Riemannian, yes. Otherwise, no. (4) yes, but certain theorems for the finite case fail to hold for the infinite.